# Что делает это регулярное выражение?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

```
$str = mb_ereg_replace('^[\ ]+', '', $str);
```

удаляет все пробелы в начале строки?

и зачем там косая черта?

вообще допустим мне нужно выбрать символ точку `[.]` нужно ли писать эту косую черту там и экранировать вот так `[\.]`

тестировал что так что так одинаково, в чем подвох?

Answer (score 3):

Ни точку, ни пробел не надо экранировать внутри [символьного класса](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php). О том, что еще там не так, можно почитать на [хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112016/), в [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) или погуглить на тему метасимволов и символьных классов.

Answer (score 2):

Подвох в том, что шаблон "." соответствует [**любому** символу](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.dot.php), и в частности знаку пунктуации "точка". Если же вы используете косую черту перед точкой, то такой шаблон будет искать **только** знак пунктуации "точка".

Если не используется модификатор '[`X`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php)' (а у вас его как раз и нет), то "слэш со следующим за ним символом без специального значения трактуется как опечатка". Т.е. этот слэш попросту игнорируется.

Кстати, да, регулярка выберет все пробелы от начала строки. Странно только что она не обрамлена в какие либо символы, например так:

```
'/^[\ ]+/'
```

Comment: ereg, это posix-выражения, они не должны быть обрамлены.

Comment: Спасибо, был не в курсе :-)

Comment: Не за что :)

Comment: А разве в [] не читаются символы как есть? Точка как символ точки.

Comment: нет, [] показывает, что может быть один из перечисленных внутри [].

Comment: [Метасимволы внутри и вне символьных классов](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112016/)

Comment: Хм... Не думал об этом. И ведь действительно получается, что их там можно не ставить! :)